# Formatting columns inside of an ASP Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I'm using an ASP repeater on my page, and I want it to create a 3 column grid.  In my HTML page, I use a class which sets the third column so that it fits.  Basically, the first 2 columns have a `margin-right` of `28px` so it spaces them nicely and then the third class removes the `margin-right` so that the columns fit.

Problem is, when this comes into the repeater, I can't use the third class and I get a 2 column result.  Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this *without* the use of a `<table>`.  It turned out that the `<form>` didn't have enough width, so I amended this and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `<table>`.  I know, I know, we aren't supposed to use tables anymore, right?  If you are displaying tabular data, you *should* use a table.  If it's a "grid", that sounds like tabular data to me.  Is it?

Comment: +1. Thanks for your time, but I managed to resolve it without the use of a table.